# How to load a OpenCL buffer into a OpenCV cv::umat with the Transparent API?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

OpenCV's transparent API looks cool but I'm having some runtime problems for custom kernels when trying to package the thing into a static build (everything works with a dll, buts thats a question for a different post).

I plan to use  which appears to run without incident.

I need 2 functions that take in umat, my own versions are slower then the OpenCV ones.

How do I something similar to this using the new API?

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat wrapme(frame.height,frame.width,CV_8U,in_d);
cv::cuda::GpuMat histo(1, bn, CV_32SC1,histoBuff_d);
cv::cuda::calcHist(wrapme,histo);
histo.download(wrapmecpu);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have compile opencv I suggest you to read the file `histogram.cpp` in the folder `src`  of the module `imgproc`.

In this file start you reading at the line 1539 (for opencv 3.1).
The most interesting part is written between line 1616 and line 1620 :

```
CV_OCL_RUN(images.total() == 1 && channels.size() == 1 && images.channels(0) == 1 &&
           channels[0] == 0 && images.isUMatVector() && mask.empty() && !accumulate &&
           histSize.size() == 1 && histSize[0] == BINS && ranges.size() == 2 &&
           ranges[0] == 0 && ranges[1] == BINS,
           ocl_calcHist(images, hist))
```

You can read here the conditions you code must satisfy to allow the library **to try** to use opencl.
If you do not satisfy these conditions OpenCV will not try to call OpenCL T-API.
If `ocl_calcHist` return false the "standard" code is call.

The following sample try to answer to your question :

```
cv::Mat1b tmp_b = cv::Mat1b::zeros(cv::theRNG().uniform(0,480),cv::theRNG().uniform(0,640)); // Mat1b == Mat_<uchar> == Mat(r,c,CV_8UC1,...);

std::for_each(tmp_b.begin(),tmp_b.end(),[&](uchar& v){ v = cv::theRNG().uniform(0,255);}); // Fill the matrix with random values following a uniform law.

cv::UMat img;

tmp_b.copyTo(img); // It's also possible to write b = tmp_b.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_RW);

cv::UMat h;

std::vector<int> channels = {0}; // Analyze only the channel 0.
std::vector<int> hsize = {256}; //Quantize the intensities in the image using 256 levels even if all the levels are not present.
std::vector<float> hranges = {0,256}; // The range is between 0 - 255 (so less than 256).

cv::calcHist(std::vector<cv::UMat>(1,img),channels,cv::noArray(),h,hsize,hranges);

cv::Mat tmp_h;

h.copyTo(tmp_h); // I also possible to write : tmp_h = h.getMat(cv::ACCESS_RW);

std::cout<<tmp_h<<std::endl;
```